# How to rewrite query without adding column names to GROUP BY

Tags: postgresql

> ERROR:  column "p.PropName" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

I'm getting the error above on the below query (PostgreSQL). How can I rewrite this to include all columns from `p` / `EXTR_Parcel`?

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(p. "Major", p. "Minor") AS "pin",
    p.*,
    json_agg(json_build_object('year', a. "RollYr", 'landVal', a. "LandVal", 'impsVal', a. "ImpsVal")) AS "appraisalHistory"
FROM
    "EXTR_Parcel" AS p
    LEFT JOIN "EXTR_RealPropApplHist_V" AS a ON p. "Major" = a. "Major"
        AND p. "Minor" = a. "Minor"
    GROUP BY
        p. "Major",
        p. "Minor";
```

Comment: Remove `p.*` from the select list.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, but I want to show all columns in `p`.

Comment: Then remove `GROUP_BY` and instead use `json_agg` as an analytic function with a partition on (major, minor).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, would you mind posting a query? I tried googling this, not turning up many results.. Thank you.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do here.  Please make this a complete question by including sample table data, along with the output you want to see.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL, you have to add *all* columns that appear in the `SELECT` list outside an aggregate function to the `GROUP BY` clause.

In PostgreSQL it is enough to specify the primary key column(s), then the database can infer all other columns.

So, assuming that `id` is the primary key of the table `"EXTR_Parcel"` (what a dreadful name), you could use

```
GROUP BY p.id
```

But it is almost always a bad idea to use `*` in the `SELECT` list, because changes in the table can lead to unexpected result set changes and sometimes errors.